# How to test if two independent variables correlations are statistically different?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, correlation, pearson-r

I have two independent variables (A and B), and one dependant variable (Y). I can calculate all the correlations (A-B, A-Y, B-Y...).

I see a difference between the Pearson correlations A-Y and B-Y (e.g.: 0.86 and 0.94). How to check whether this difference is statistically different?

There should be also a bottom limit for the sample size. How do I calculate that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A variable in common (overlap) e.g. of form r(W,X) = r(W,Z).

> A test for this comparison goes under various names the Williams test, Williams-Hotelling or Hotelling test.

Cited from https://imaging.mrc-cbu.cam.ac.uk/statswiki/FAQ/WilliamsSPSS where the use of SPSS is also dicussed.

http://crr.ugent.be/archives/546 has a formula to conduct that.

Williams-Hotelling and Steiger-Test are implemented in R in the package `psych` in the function `r.test`: https://personality-project.org/r/psych/help/r.test.html

The publication by Steiger cited on the help page to `psych::r.test` can be found here: http://ww.w.statpower.net/Steiger%20Biblio/Steiger80.pdf

There also is an online calculator for these tests here: https://blogs.gwu.edu/weissba/teaching/calculators/hotellings-t-and-steigers-z-tests/

I have found a more modern overview and treatment of the question of which methods to use when here, however tl;dr; ;-) : [https://uh.edu/~ttian/dependentCorr.pdf](https://uh.edu/%7Ettian/dependentCorr.pdf)

Comment: you're amazing. Thanks a lot for all the resources!